# AngularJS: Error after minify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

After minifying my AngularJS app, I'm getting this error:

> n is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict
>   mode

I think it comes from this decorator:

```
(function () {


    function logDecoratorConfig($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$log', logDecorator);
    }

    function logDecorator($delegate) {

        $delegate.debug = function (msg) {
            var time = new Date().toString();
            console.log(time + " : " + msg);
        };

        return $delegate;
    }

    angular.module('services')
        .config(['$provide', logDecoratorConfig]);
}());
```

Maybe it is because the `logDecorator` function has to be annotated too? How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to provide minification safe injection of the `$delegate` service into `logDecorator` function. Try below two options.

Option #1:

```
function logDecoratorConfig($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$log', ['$delegate', logDecorator]);
}
```

Option #2:

```
function logDecoratorConfig($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$log', logDecorator);
}

function logDecorator($delegate) {

    $delegate.debug = function (msg) {
        var time = new Date().toString();
        console.log(time + " : " + msg);
    };

    return $delegate;
}

logDecorator.$inject = ['$delegate'];
```

Comment: After applying those options the error still exists, so I think the problem is that the `logDecorator` function has to be annotated. How can I do that?

Comment: Above options both provide explicit annotation. If the error persists it means that there are another place that needs to be annotated.

Comment: Thanks, @dfsq. You were right. there was another place with the same issue.